# How do I add 90 days to a date BUT find the closest Wednesday to that 90 day period in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a document that I create every Wednesday with a return/check date of Wednesday, three months after the document is created.

I am currently using =EDATE(E6,3) to add 90 days, but how can I adjust for the result to be Wednesday at 90 days +/- a couple of days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version

`=WORKDAY.INTL(EDATE(E6,3)-4,1,"1101111")`

By subtracting 4 days from your original result and finding the next Wednesday you get the **nearest** Wednesday, i.e. the only Wednesday in the 7 day period +/- 3 days

For older versions of Excel (if `WORKDAY.INTL` function is not available) you can use this formula for the same result:

`=EDATE(E6,3)+4-WEEKDAY(EDATE(E6,3))`

Answer (score 0):

```
A1=2017-10-27
B1=A1+90
C1=WEEKDAY(B1)
D1=B1+4-C1

D1 is the date of wednesday
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question!

By combining the EDATE and WEEKDAY Functions, we can always find the closes Wednesday by using one of the following formulas:

If you want to go to the closest Wednesday in either direction

```
=EDATE(E6,3)-(WEEKDAY(EDATE(E6,3),1)-4)
```

If you want to always have the Wednesday closest to the future date without going past the future date (Price is Right method)

```
=EDATE(C3,3)-IF(WEEKDAY(EDATE(C3,3),1)<4,WEEKDAY(EDATE(C3,3),1)+3,WEEKDAY(EDATE(C3,3),1)-4)
```

What we are doing is finding what day of the week the 3 month future date falls on.  The "1" parameter tells Excel to use a week that starts on Sunday.  This way we know if our future date falls before or after a Wednesday (which is day 4).

In the first option, we only want the closest Wednesday, even if it is a few days ahead.  By subtracting the weekday of the future date by 4 (Wed) we always end up with the Wednesday of that week.

In the second option, we only want the Wednesday that is before our future date.  Thus we introduce an IF function to determine whether or not the date is before Wednesday or not.  If it is before, we add 3 to the number of weekdays, before subtracting it from the future date.  Thus, if our future date was on a Tuesday, we would subtract a total of 6 days (Tues = 3, +3 days), which would give us the preceding Wednesday.  Also, if our future date was a Sunday, we'd get Sunday minus 4 days, which would also be a Wednesday.  On the other hand, if it's greater than 4, we stick with our original formula which will subtract the number of days past Wednesday from out future date, which will return that Wednesday.

I hope this was helpful, and I wish you luck on your Excel Endeavors!

Comment: For the second version you could achieve the same result with a formula very similar to your first one, i.e. `=EDATE(C3,3)+1-WEEKDAY(EDATE(C3,3)-3)`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! That makes a lot of sense